# UWPアプリからMySQLへの接続でエラーが解消できない

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

VS2019にてC# UWPアプリの作成しています。

NuGetにてMySql.Dataもv8.0.22をインストール済み。

同一ネットワーク内で稼働するMySQLサーバーに接続する簡単なサンプルを、チュートリアルに従って作成していますが、`open()` でエラーとなり原因が分からない状態です。

接続するデータベースのユーザーの特権は設定済みで、サンプルを動作させている端末から、MySQL workbench、VSのサーバーエクスプロラーの接続は正常に行われています。自分のサンプルのみエラーが発生しています。

MySQL Workbench,サーバーエクスプローラーでの接続が可能であることから、ポートのコンフリクションはないかと考えています。

下記に抜粋したソースを貼ります。データベース名(hoge)とアカウント情報(fuga/fuga)は便宜上変更しています。

```
// mysql test
string M_str_sqlcon = "database=hoge;server=192.168.11.150;user id=fuga;password=fuga;";
MySqlConnection mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection(M_str_sqlcon);
MySqlCommand mysqlcom = new MySqlCommand("select * from mtr_ages", mysqlcon);
mysqlcon.Open();
```

エラー:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (アクセス許可で禁じられた方法でソケットにアクセスしようとしました。 192.168.11.150:3306)
```

原因、又は解決のアイディアをお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたらレスを頂ければ助かります。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: モデレーターの皆様、修正ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

MSDNのフォーラムで対処方法を教えて頂き解決しました。Package.appxmanifestでプライベートネットワーク(クライアントとサーバー）を有効にしたところ解決出来ました。